# HTML/PHP email form

Tags: javascript, php, html

My mailer form isn't works. If it possible please take a look and give me some answer to make it work. <3

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
if($_POST) {
$EmailFrom = "blah";
$EmailTo = "blah";
$Subject = "blah";
$Name1 = $_POST['Name1']; 
$Name2= $_POST['Name2']; 
$Name3 = $_POST['Name3']; 
$Name4 = $_POST['Name4']; 
$Name5 = $_POST['Name5']; 
$Email = $_POST['Email']; 
$TeamName = $_POST['TeamName']; 
$Message = $_POST['Message']; 
$Body = "";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Player1: ";
$Body .= $Name1;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Player2: ";
$Body .= $Name2;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Player3: ";
$Body .= $Name3;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Player4: ";
$Body .= $Name4;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Player5: ";
$Body .= $Name5;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "TeamName: ";
$Body .= $TeamName;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Megjegyzes: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");


}
?>
```

I tried many methods but seems like I don't really know something. 
In HTMLI used this method:

Here is the HTML:

```html
<form action="contact.php" class="contact-form" method="post">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" name="Name1" class="form-control" id="name1" placeholder="Játékos 1">
        <input type="text" name="Name2" class="form-control" id="name2" placeholder="Játékos 2">
        <input type="text" name="Name3" class="form-control" id="name3" placeholder="Játékos 3">
        <input type="text" name="Name4" class="form-control" id="name4" placeholder="Játékos 4">
        <input type="text" name="Name5" class="form-control" id="name5" placeholder="Játékos 5">  
        <p> Még <strong> 16 </strong>  csapat számára van hely! </p>  
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="email" name="Email" class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Email">
                                <input type="text" name="TeamName" class="form-control" id="TeamName" placeholder="Csapatnév">  
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="Message" rows="25" cols="10" placeholder="  Megjegyzés (nem kötelező)"></textarea>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default submit-btn form_submit">Jelentkezés</button>
         <p> A jelentkezéssel elfogadjátok a verseny szabályzatát és feltételeit. </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

What can be wrong? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: without the rest of the form, it's guesswork from hereon in.

Comment: If you can't be bothered to explain **HOW** this doesn't work, we won't be bothered to try and **GUESS** what the problem might be.

Comment: @MarcB why don't you ever ask questions? Whats your second account you use to ask questions?

Comment: Can't post the full code cuz it's noticed me that i use too many code in my question.

Comment: @AndreFerraz: I could tell you, but then I'd have to kill you? kidding... my real job doesn't involve php anymore, and is so highly focused it'd be futile asking here, so this is how I distract myself from that.

Comment: I added the full form. If it possible, please answer my question asap.

Comment: @MarcB haha, when I look at you guys "the ones with high reputation", you lot seem to never ask questions .. Was just wondering .

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$EmailFrom = "blah";
$EmailTo = "blah";
$Subject = "blah";
$Name1 = $_POST['Name1']; 
$Name2= $_POST['Name2']; 
$Name3 = $_POST['Name3']; 
$Name4 = $_POST['Name4']; 
$Name5 = $_POST['Name5']; 
$Email = $_POST['Email']; 
$TeamName = $_POST['TeamName']; 
$Message = $_POST['Message']; 
$Body = "";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Player1: ";
$Body .= $Name1;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Player2: ";
$Body .= $Name2;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Player3: ";
$Body .= $Name3;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Player4: ";
$Body .= $Name4;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Player5: ";
$Body .= $Name5;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "TeamName: ";
$Body .= $TeamName;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Megjegyzes: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");


}
?>
```